# How to get standard error from constrained optimization problem in R?

Tags: r, optimization, calibration

Can I get standard error from a constrained optimization problem in R? I have calculated transition probabilities. Now I am trying to calibrate it. Using these transition probabilities I have simulated a distribution. When I compare the simulated distribution with real data, I found a significant difference. To tune the calculated distribution I am trying to use constrained optimization techniques. I have calculated the optimized transition probabilities now wondering can I calculate the standard deviation too.

Here is my code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stats)
library(readxl)

target <- read_excel("Validation.xlsx", sheet="Distribution", 
    range="W4:AB13", col_names = c("Abstinent", "Low", "Medium", 
           "High", "Very High", "AD")) |> as.matrix()

objectivefuntion <- function(Sim, real){
  Sim_mat=matrix(Sim, nrow=6, ncol=6)
  # simulated data is the same size as the real data
  sim_data=0*real
  # set the initial cohort size to 100 abstinent users
  sim_data[1, 1]=100
  
  j=1
  for(i in 2:dim(real)[[1]]){
    sim_data[i,]=sim_data[j,] %*% Sim_mat
    j=i
  }
  
  rmse <- sqrt(mean((as.matrix(sim_data) - as.matrix(real))^2))
  
  # Return the RMSE (the objective to be minimized in Bayesian optimization)
  return(rmse)
  }


parameter<-matrix(c(.796,0.106, 0.04,   0.03,   0.028,  0,
              0.3,  0.27,   0.126,  0.144,  0.12,   0.04,
              0.21, 0.158,  0.203,  0.185,  0.185,  0.058,
              0.145,    0.107,  0.133,  0.219,  0.283,  0.114,
              0.147,    0.035,  0.078,  0.16,   0.43,   0.15,
              0,    0,0,    0,0,1
), ncol = 6, nrow = 6, byrow = TRUE)

# make sure that parameter vector rows sum to 1
parameter=parameter/(rowSums(parameter)%x%t(rep(1, 6)))

# parameter vector is 6-by-6, so 36 elements. Each element is bounded between zero and 1. Need
# to state the constraint as u_i*theta-ci>=0, to enforce a 0 lower bound u_i is 1
lower_bounds <- diag(1, length(as.vector(parameter)))
lower_bounds_ci=rep(0, length(as.vector(parameter)))

# now the upper bounds: theta <= 1 implies 1-theta>=0, so we need u_i 
# equal to -1 and c_i equal to -1 to 
upper_bounds<-diag(-1,length(as.vector(parameter)))
upper_bounds_ci=rep(-1,length(as.vector(parameter)))

# now the equality constraints. Each row sums to 1. Trick is that EACH row of the matrix is a separate constraint
equality_bounds=matrix(NA,ncol=length(as.vector(parameter)), nrow=6)
equality_bounds_ci=rep(1,6)

for(i in 1:6) {
  eq_mat=0*parameter
  eq_mat[i,]=1
  equality_bounds[i,]=as.vector(eq_mat)
}

# now construct the ui matrix
ui=rbind(
  lower_bounds,
  upper_bounds
  ,equality_bounds
)

# now construct the ci vector
ci=c(
  lower_bounds_ci,
  upper_bounds_ci
  ,equality_bounds_ci
  )-1*10^-10

theta=as.vector(parameter)

# check interior
min(ui%*%theta-ci)
# now estimate

optimized_probs <- constrOptim(theta = theta,
                               f = objectivefuntion,
                               grad = NULL,
                               ui = ui,
                               ci = ci,
                               real=target)


final_transition_probs <- matrix(optimized_probs$par, nrow = 6)
```

I am trying to calibrate my initial transition probabilities so that the simulated distribution look like real world data.

Comment: Please do not include `rm(list = ls())`  in code posted here!

Comment: ‘setwd’ is not helpful either.